Definition and physical meaning of luminosity distance
I am reading Kolb and Turner and they define the luminosity distance as
$$d_L^2:=\frac{\mathcal{L}}{4\pi\mathcal{F}}$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the energy detected by some detector per time and detector surface, $\mathcal{L}$ is the energy emitted by a source per time.
This definition makes sense to me but I don't understand the next step. They say
$$d_L^2=R^2(t_0)r_1^2(1+z)^2 (*)$$
where $R(t)$ is the scale factor, $t_1$ is the time when the signal is emitted from a source at $r_1$. $t_0$ is the time when the signal is detected at $r_0=0$ The red-shift is defined as $1+z=R(t_0)/R(t_1)$.
Kolb and Turner justify the expression $(*)$ by saying that at time $t_0$ the effective surface is larger (that's where the $R^2(t_0)r_1$ factor comes from) and the energy is reduced (one factor (1+z)) and the wavelength is red-shifted (another factor of (1+z)). My first question: Is there a way to derive this result? The argument looks super hand-waving to me.
My second question: Is $d_L$ really a physical distance? If I'd define a distance measure at some time $t_0$ I'd define it as follows. Consider a source that emits a photon signal at time $t_1$ which arrives at the detector at $t_0$. Then the distance is to the source at time $t_0$ is $c(t_0-t_1)$. In other words:
$$ds^2=0=dt^2-R^2dt^2\Rightarrow \int_{t_1}^{t_0}\frac{dt}{R(t)}=\int_{r_1}^{r_0}dr=r_1$$
then if we know $R(t)$ we can solve the time integral and obtain $c(t_0-t_1)$. Why is that not being used as a distance measure?

question 1: the luminosity distance relates the luminosity of a source to the observed flux. It accounts for the expanding universe (which dilutes flux) and photon-(redshift) (which reduces energy), leading to the formula for luminosity distance.
question 2: the comoving distance measures spatial separation but doesn’t account for redshift or flux dilution. While luminosity distance relates observed flux to intrinsic luminosity, factoring in both effects.
question 3: luminosity distance measures how cosmic expansion and redshift affect the observed flux not just the spatial separation, so its obvious thers a link between observed flux and source luminosity in an expanding universe.
